# Adding the username into a URL to redirect to a specific page

Tags: shortcode, url-rewriting

I need to add the username in the URL.This is to redirect specific users to specific pages. I have added the following code in my functions.php file in my theme folder.:

```
function my_redirect_function() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $userdata;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $username = $userdata->user_login;
        $url = 'https://myurl.com/user/‘.$username;

        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect_function' );
```

But I am getting the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'template_redirect' (T_STRING) in /home/instantt/public_html/wp-content/themes/panoramic/functions.php on line 490

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

I recommend switching to a code editor with PHP syntax highlighting, such as PHPStorm/Sublime/Atom/etc, which would reveal the problem on this line of code, as shown in the highlighting on your question once the code block is formatted:

```
$url = 'https://myurl.com/user/‘.$username;
```

The closing quote, is actually an apostrophe `‘` not `'`. As a result the closing quote is actually just before `template_redirect`

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom! That worked. I will use a code editor next time.  I am getting a different error but I will first try to figure it out

Comment: Thanks, if the answer's correct can you mark it as correct via the tick underneath the vote counter?

Comment: Hi TomI don't see the where I can tick under the vote counter?